# SX1276_FSK Modem_Maximum Payload Length

Tags: lora, fifo, fsk, sx1276

I've been scanning the SX1276 datasheet recently and found the thing that puzzled me. It says that in *Packet Mode* the device is using FIFO as the payload source. The maximum size is **2047 bytes** for FSK/OOK (screenshot + **chapter 4.2.13.2 of the datasheet**)
[image]

However, when looking at the FIFO chapter of the datasheet we see that the size of the buffer is fixed to **64 bytes**

[image]

Since most examples on the Internet suggest a maximum message size of 64 bytes, I wonder how the 2047 byte size is achieved in the SX1276 FSK/OOK modem?

Comment: The FIFO is an elastic buffer. As long as you don’t let the fifo get empty, you can send unlimited lengths. A FIFO is like a bucket with a drain pipe. The drain pipe is the data as it gets sent out the radio. When the bucket gets low, you need to put some more data in. The bucket can only hold 64 bytes at a time. You might decide to refill when it gets down 5 or 10 bytes or thereabouts.